# ConTeXt: Numbers as verbal strings (e.g. 1=“first”)

Tags: formatting, context, number, fmtcount

With LaTeX, I can use the `fmtcount` package to typeset numbers as verbal strings and print e.g. “one”, “One”, “first” or “First” instead of 1 and “twenty-two”, “Twenty-two”, “twenty-second” or “Twenty-second” instead of 22. Is there some ready-made way to do this with ConTeXt? Does it support different languages?

Comment: There are things like `\startitemize[ordinal][width=2em] \dorecurse{150}{\item test} \stopitemize` but that print 1st and so on. I therefore guess it is a matter of entering what should be there. If you send a mail to the context list that you volunteer, I'm sure somebody will tell you what data to provide.

Comment: The only thing which is supported out of the box is the `word` conversion, e.g. `\starttext \dorecurse{100}{\convertnumber{word}{#1}, } \stoptext
`. When you need only a short list of ordinal numbers you can create your own conversion set with `\defineconversion [en] [ordinal_numbers] [first,second,third,fourth,fifth]` and access it with the new name, e.g. `\starttext \dorecurse{5}{\convertnumber{ordinal_numbers}{#1}, } \stoptext`.

Comment: Mind providing an example of what you'd like to achieve? A sample input document and expected output would be helpful.